# Como converter um atributo string de um dado Model contendo um XML (Danfe) para PDF (ASP.NET Core)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nfe

Peço perdão se a pergunta não foi específica o suficiente, mas sou iniciante em ASP.NET Core. Long story short, eu preciso ter um endpoint que devolve um arquivo PDF para o front-end da aplicação, PDF esse que correponde a uma DANFe. No respectivo Controller que lida com esse Model (citado abaixo), já consigo passar o atributo "XmlDanfe" para XML, mas a dúvida é em como consigo obter um PDF. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

```
public class DanfesXml
{
    [JsonPropertyName("XmlDanfe")]
    public string XmlDanfe { get; set; } // já está sendo alimentado através de um WebService
}
```

Comment: Felipe, vc pode usar alguma bibilioteca de geração  de  pdf, procure por pdf nuget package isso deve te auxiliar a criar um pdf, para exibição  você pode fazer um retorno do tipo file etc, recomendo vc procurar por 'return file .net core on controller'.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.